# How to disable Images/CSS in Puppeteer?

Tags: python-3.x, puppeteer, pyppeteer

How to disable images/CSS in Puppeteer?
I've seen this tutorial https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-increase-web-scraping-speed-using-puppeteer/
but I don't know how to translate it to Python

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on example from https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/blob/dev/pyppeteer/page.py#L312:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(True)
async def intercept(request):
    if any(request.resourceType == _ for _ in ('stylesheet', 'image', 'font')):
        await request.abort()
    else:
        await request.continue_()
page.on('request', lambda req: asyncio.ensure_future(intercept(req)))
```

Answer (score 3):

This below code will disable resource by type: `fetch`, `image`, `media`, and `font`.

```
    page.setRequestInterception(true)

    page.on ( 'request', async request => {
        if ( request.resourceType () === 'fetch' || request.resourceType () === 'image' || request.resourceType () === 'media' || request.resourceType () === 'font' ) {
            request.abort ()
        } else {
            request.continue ()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I want it in Python for Pyppeteer.